# grub-install from live CD

Tags: grub

I have removed my MBR by mistake. Now I can't boot Ubuntu, so I want to reinstall grub.

I'm getting this error:

```
grub-install --boot-directory=/media/cab64688-2d97-4bbd-9f32-7bc0badb40a8/boot /dev/sdb
rm: cannot remove `/media/cab64688-2d97-4bbd-9f32-7bc0badb40a8/boot/grub/915resolution.mod': Read-only file system
```

So, the problem is that my existing Ubuntu partition is mounted read only. When I try:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb7  /media/ubuntu_mpt
mount: block device /dev/sdb7 is write-protected, mounting read-only
```

So I failed to install grub since I'm in read only mode.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** After apt-get install grub, I repeated the process and got:

```
Probing devices to guess BIOS drives. This may take a long time.
Unknown partition table signature
sed: can't read /media/cab64688-2d97-4bbd-9f32-7bc0badb40a8_/boot/grub/device.map: No such file or directory
grep: /media/cab64688-2d97-4bbd-9f32-7bc0badb40a8_/boot/grub/device.map: No such file or directory
/dev/sda does not have any corresponding BIOS drive.
```

Comment: I doubt that anyone would respond faster if you attach the word *urgent* in your post. If anything, they might even avoid helping in the first place. I could be wrong.

Comment: You need to mount /dev/sdb7 with read-write permissions.

Comment: Yes, but I can't do that from live CD. I fixed it with UNetbootin http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=690912.

Comment: What kind of storage medium is `/dev/sdb`? What is your partition layout (on both `sda` and `sdb`)?

Comment: It's regular HDD.

Comment: You may need to recreate your partition map on that drive before installing GRUB. At least, you should verify that it's right before installing GRUB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb7  /media/ubuntu_mpt
```

This should be:

```
$ sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdb7
```

This will not mount it again, but change the already existing mount to rw.

Comment: Thanks, didn't tried it, but I hope it works.